# CloudFront -> ELB -> Pod running Gunicorn

Tags: nginx, amazon-cloudfront

Can anyone tell me if there's a "killer" reason to put NGINX in front Kubernetes pods running Gunicorn?

externally, I have CloudFront hitting an ELB which in turn engages the pods running Gunicorn with my Django based API server.

Since Caching is handled by CloudFront, and it's flexible enough for routing rules  -- is there any good reason to add NGINX to the mix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx will help you in performing the below items if you need some of them, Then I would say it make sense to add it to the stack

- Optimize the caching (you can also cache dynamic content.
- Restrict access to the services (based on ips).
- Implement basic auth for some services.
- Load balancing traffic between different posds or services.
- Rewrite URLS.
- Pass extra headers or configs to the backend services.